# Browser drops connection during model training

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I am currently trying to go through a fairly long hyperparameter grid search (4-5 hours) and I keep having issues with Jupyter Lab (or haven't figured out something yet) on a gcp notebook instance. The browser connection to the notebook keeps dropping, whereas the training process continues just fine. When it finishes training process, there's nowhere to write the output as the browser connection to the notebook has already dropped.

How can I keep that connection alive or make sure the output gets written into the notebook even if my laptop gets turned off/gets turned off?

Comment: Have you tried writting the output of the grid search to a simple .txt file? That way when you connect back to the notebook you have your results in there

Comment: @Joaquim that would definitely work but I am looking for a way to make sure that the output of model training will end up in my notebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems that may be affecting your notebook. It can be a GCP issue, a network issue... Therefore, you need to provide more information in order to diagnose what is happening. I would recommend you to open a ticket with GCP or Jupyter support to conduct a more thorough investigation as it can be something  difficult to diagnose and they will have more tools to do it. Also, what @Joaquim suggested seems like a good workaround for the moment. Anyhow, I have gathered several troubleshooting steps that you can follow to find if it is one of this recurrent issues the one that is affecting you:

1. According to [this Jupyter Notebook document](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html), there is a ‘shutdown_no_activity_timeout’ option. The default value is ‘0’ that disables this automatic shutdown. The option might be overridden on ‘jupyter_notebook_config.py’ file. You may follow these steps to confirm it:

   - Click on the instance name of in which your Notebook is running on the [AI Platform Notebooks page](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/notebooks/create-new#open_a_notebook).
   - Remote access it by clicking “SSH”
   - Run this on the shell to confirm the existence of the overriding:
     `ls /home/*/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`
   - Run this command to confirm if the shutdown_no_activity_timeout option is doing the overriding:
     `cat /home/*/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py | grep shutdown_no_activity_timeout`
   - Switch the option to ‘0’ if it is set to a different value, and reset the Notebook instances on [this page](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/notebooks/create-new#open_a_notebook) to apply the change.
2. According to [this other document](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html#known-issues), it might fail to connect when behind a proxy. You can try to [disable your browser’s proxy settings](https://www.expressvpn.com/support/troubleshooting/google-chrome-no-proxy).
3. You can also try to change the Jupyter port. On [this Jupyter issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1845), the customer insists that his disconnection problem was gone after changing it. If you are using Chrome browser, could you please open the Inspect panel (Ctrl+Shift+I) and compare your connection symptoms with [this image](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1845#issuecomment-255623563)? If you get similar errors, you may try to change the port (c.NotebookApp.port).

Comment: Thanks Javier for the extensive answer, will most definitely tinker with it as soon as I'll have some spare time. Another approach that crossed my mind would be to install `screen` on the gcp instance, launch a new session and execute the notebook via `jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --inplace --execute /home/path/to/nb.ipynb`. This way the terminal session should be preserved even if I shut down my personal laptop and allowed to be resumed with `screen -r`.