# Vertex AI notebook kernel lost on PC sleep

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

While using Vertex AI notebook instance kernel on GCP, the notebook gets detached everytime my system sleeps.

How can I keep my notebook running even if my system shuts down?

Answer (score 1):

The Jupyter community has discussed this issue for quite a while now. There is no fix as such but there is a workaround to buffer the output and then display it when the notebook is opened again.

This answer is adopted from the comment from this [Stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59391254/browser-drops-connection-during-model-training#comment105963029_59857547). I’ve also seen this workaround being suggested in a [Jupyter Github issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1647#issuecomment-353110058).

> The workaround would be to install the “Screen” utility (terminal multiplexer) on the GCE instance where JupyterHub is hosted, launch a new terminal session from JupyterHub and execute the notebook using the below “nbconvert” command.

```
jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --inplace --execute /home/path/to/notebook.ipynb
```

> This way the terminal session could be preserved even if the personal computer is shut down and allow it to be resumed with the `screen -r` command.